# Style header of Bootstrap accordion that has the class "collapse show"

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I want to style the card header of the panel that has the class `collapse show`. In the example here it's the first panel. I tried using CSS by using

```
    .accordion .card .card-header button .btn.btn-link:not(.collapsed){
  background-color: #FEB7EE
}
```

However, this doesn't work unfortunately. Is there a solution that uses CSS only? Or do I have to use JavaScript for this?

```css
.accordion .card .card-header button:not(.collapsed) {
  color: #0c63e4;
  background-color: #FEB7EE;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer.

There was issue in the way you were targeting the .collapsed class, below is the correct one:

```
#accordion .card .card-header button.btn.btn-link:not(.collapsed){
```

background-color: #FEB7EE;
color: #0c63e4;
}

```css
.card-header{padding:0 !important}
.btn.btn-link{
 text-align: left;
 width: 100%;
  padding:.75rem 1.25rem;
  }
  /* Using OG css*/
  #accordion .card .card-header button.btn.btn-link:not(.collapsed){
  background-color: #FEB7EE;
  color: #0c63e4;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly in your code snippet! I thought I could also style the .btn.btn-link like this: `.accordion .card .card-header button .btn.btn-link:not(.collapsed) {
  background-color: #FEB7EE;` but it doesn't function. Do you why that is? or is it also CSS override?
}'

Comment: updated answer.. there was issue with your target css